# NsmutableArray only show last object added at all index paths

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

i am stuck at a very little point. i want to show dummy data from array to tableView. But i always get only last object at all index paths. i don t know why it is overriding by last object

```
-(NSMutableArray *)clubTypes
{
    NSMutableArray *clubTypeDataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ClubTypeDC *clubTypes = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];
//    slideMenu_dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 1;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Hot tonight";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_hot_tonight.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_hot_tonight_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 2;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Lounges";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_lounges.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_lounges_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 3;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Pubs/Sports bars";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_pubs.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_pubs_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 4;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Shesha bars";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_shisha_bars.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_shisha_bars_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 5;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Ladies night";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_ladies_night.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_ladies_night_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 6;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Music festivals";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_music_festivals.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_music_festivals_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 7;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Boat parties";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_boat_parties.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_boat_parties_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 8;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Evening brunches";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_evening_brunches.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_evening_brunches_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 9;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Beach/ Description";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_beach_parties.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_beach_parties_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 10;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Configuration";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_configuration.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_configuration_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 11;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"About Unighted";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_about.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_about_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

//    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    return clubTypeDataArray;

}
```

please help me where is a problem.

Comment: You need to `clubTypes = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];` every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not creating new objects, you just keep adding and modifying the same object over and over again.

Do this instead:

```
-(NSMutableArray *)clubTypes
{
    NSMutableArray *clubTypeDataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ClubTypeDC *clubTypes = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];
//    slideMenu_dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 1;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Hot tonight";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_hot_tonight.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_hot_tonight_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];
    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 2;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Lounges";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_lounges.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_lounges_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];
    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 3;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Pubs/Sports bars";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_pubs.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_pubs_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    ...
}
```

Comment: can you tell me what is the reason behind this?

Comment: You have the same object at every position in the array, you were only modifying it's properties. When you modify one it modifies every element since they are the same, added over and over again. With the suggested solution you create a new instance in every step, so when you change it, the rest are not affected.

Answer (score 2):

Note that every time you add object to an array it is the same object.

You have to create new object each time you configure it, so the code:

```
ClubTypeDC *clubTypes = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];
```

Should prepend all the configuration snippets.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate `ClubTypeDC` every time for new object, otherwise you will edit the properties of same object reference. Thats why all elements in the array gets updated with last updated data

```
-(NSMutableArray *)clubTypes
{
    NSMutableArray *clubTypeDataArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    ClubTypeDC *clubTypes = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];
    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 1;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Hot tonight";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_hot_tonight.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_hot_tonight_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    clubTypes = [[ClubTypeDC alloc] init];
    clubTypes.clubTypeID = 2;
    clubTypes.clubTypeTitle = @"Lounges";
    clubTypes.clubTypeImage = @"icon_lounges.png";
    clubTypes.clubTypeSelectedImage = @"icon_lounges_touch.png";
    [clubTypeDataArray addObject:clubTypes];

    .....
 }
```